# Epsilon-delta proof of multivariable limit [f(x+dx,y+dy)-f(x,y+dy)]/dx

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

When can we prove that 
$$\lim_{(dx,dy)\to(0,0)} \frac{f(x+dx,y+dy)-f(x,y+dy)}{dx} = f_x(x,y)$$

I'm willing to assume that $f_x$ and $f_y$ are continuous.

Here is my failed proof attempt:

By algebra,
$$\begin{align*}
&\frac{f(x+dx,y+dy)-f(x,y+dy)}{dx}\\
&=\frac{f(x+dx,y)-f(x,y)}{dx}+\frac{f(x+dx,y+dy)-f(x+dx,y)}{dx}+\frac{f(x,y)-f(x,y+dy)}{dx}\\
&=A + B + C
\end{align*}$$

By definition, $\lim_{(dx,dy)\to(0,0)} A = f_x(x,y)$.
For my conjecture to be true, I must show that $\lim_{(dx,dy)\to(0,0)} B + C = 0$.
This seems unlikely, since $\lim_{(dx,dy)\to(0,0)} C$ varies depending on the relationship between dx and dy. How can I show that $\lim_{(dx,dy)\to(0,0)} B + C = 0$?

Comment: Really $$\lim_{dx\to 0} \frac{f(x+dx,y)-f(x,y)}{dx} = f_x(x,y)$$The indeterminate form $0/0$ doesn't exclude the existence of the limit.

Comment: Can you please clarify how your comment relates to my question?

Comment: If you are trying to find a derivative, you will always get an indeterminate 0/0 form because the derivative is an instantaneous change.  That means that in the limit we are looking at an interval of width 0.  However, that limit can exist.  As a trivial  example 2h/h $\rightarrow$ 2 as h $\rightarrow$ 0.  As to how you know whether the limit exists, it very much depends on the situation, and the $\epsilon-\delta$ approach is not very helpful.  You might want to go back to calc 1 and find the derivative of f(x) = x$^2$ using the limit of differences method.

Comment: I am comfortable with formally computing limits. I've updated the question to show where my proof goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding some detail, I prove the statement

*If $f$ has partial derivative $f_x$ at every point of an open ball centered at $(x,y)$ and this is continuous at $(x,y)$, then* $$\lim_{(dx,dy)\to(0,0)} \frac{f(x+dx,y+dy)-f(x,y+dy)}{dx} = f_x(x,y)$$In fact the mean value theorem (for functions of one variable) says that, if $dx \neq 0$ $$\frac{f(x+dx,y+dy)-f(x,y+dy)}{dx}=f_x(x+\theta\,dx,y+dy)$$with $0<\theta<1\,$.